# CHADIM in information technology context

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

What is CHADIM in information technology context?
My assignment for one IT class(Relational database management system) is a investigation report on CHADIM.

Can someone give me some pointers on the subject? i cant find anything related  on search engines.

Comment: Was this word all capitals in the assignment? Is it possibly a non-English language word?

Comment: maybe it is an internal acronym in your project (like ACID is well-known acronym)

Answer (score 1):

it turns out the "`CHADIM`" was abbreviation for Slowly Chaging Dimensions

Comment: Thanks for letting us know.  I have read about slowly changing dimensions in the context of data warehousing, but I've never seen anyone use "CHADIM" as an abbreviation for it.  Nor does Google find any matches.  Sounds like someone in your class made it up.